# Cryptography or quantum computing

Tags: soft-question, cryptography, quantum-computation

I’m currently a senior applied mathematics student, I love math, and plan to study master in France. I’m choosing whether to pursue master in cryptography or quantum computing. (In fact, I find some comments about quantum computing may destroy cryptography, so a bit worried my chose) I’m wondering which one is more recommended and why?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: RSA might be unsafe anyway. There are several issues (1. It could not be proven that it is safe if the enemy cannot factor the public number 2. It is not known whether factoring is hard 3. The parameters must carefully be chosen to make it resistant on the several known attacks) . That does however not mean that quantum computing (if it actually would work!) would make cryptograhpy pointless. My advice clearly is "cryptogrpahy".